# Jupyter notebook custom theme cuts off far right character of input cell

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how to extend the input cell in a custom theme so it does not cut off the last character on the right? I want a dark theme and I’ve tried the onedork and monokai and they both seem to have this cutoff. Here are examples of both:

Monokai theme – cut off “d” far right
[image]

Default theme – shows “d” far right
[image]

I have found the custom.css. Which was a great discovery
/Users/nick/.jupyter/custom/custom.css
But I do not know the parameter that will give me the effect I want.

I have tried:

1. Editing the custom.css and
2. poking around deveelopter tools Insepector to find the right parameter

Here is some research I’ve done in the custom.css that I thought would be fruitful but still hasn't solved my issue with the right border of input cells.
It seems that `div.input_area` is the element/class that I want to adjust. I’ve tried everything from changing margins, borders, padding but nothing makes it so I can see the last character in my cell.

Here is the default for monokai:

```css
div.input_area {
 background-color: #282828;
 background: #282828;
 padding-right: 1.2em;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

If I change `padding-right` to 0; it removes padding but still cuts off on the right. So maybe it's something else that makes the cell off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit div:

```css
div.CodeMirror-lines {
 padding-bottom: .9em;
 padding-left: .5em;/*<-- set this to 0*/
 padding-right: 1.5em;
 padding-top: .7em;
}
```